# Scala breeze error: could not find implicit value for parameter

Tags: scala, breeze, scala-breeze

I'm using the breeze package on scala. I simply want do to a matrix product: A*At. However I get this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpMulMatrix.Impl2[breeze.linalg.Matrix[Double],breeze.linalg.Transpose[breeze.linalg.Matrix[Double]],That]
```

I'm quite sure the problem is in the input matrix's format since it comes from a function I wrote, but I don't know how I could solve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's better if you can give a bit more context (e.g. a code snippet), but unfortunately I guess that doesn't work for Matrix (as opposed to DenseMatrix or CSCMatrix). I recommend picking one of those types and using it instead.